# Dynamically adding columns to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid

I've been trying to find a solution to this but I couldn't find what I was looking for so ultimately I think I need to change my project type but figured I'd ask in case someone can save me time / educate me. 

I have a console project that is using a created Window Form to allow some front end user interaction, but because of this I can only use a DataGrid. (The project is evolving as I make it that's why I'm in this situation.)

I would like to make something like this using a class if possible. I made the example by doing the hardcoded XAML way 
**XAML** 
[image] 
after its made using the C# below. (Red is not there I added that) 
[image: Table to Create]

This is what I have so far. 
**C#** 
[image] 
If anyone can help me out with this it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out because of another post after searching for a while. I'll just post my final solution in case anyone was wondering or stumbles upon this post. 
**C#** 
[image] 
**XAML** 
[image]